# Best way to cleanse huge amounts of data

Tags: data-warehouse, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have a huge table in my Oracle database - around 40 million rows - that I have to check that all data are correct inside fields based on some business rules.

Let us assume this is my huge table, and the rules are:

1. US only can have [national_id_type]=NID.. others must be VISA
2. US only with NA can own house.. other nationality with VISA can't own a house

[image]

What I think

1. First to land the table inside a landing table to preserve the original data
2. Rewrite error in the column to display the errors and the number of them inside a PowerBI dashboard so the quality department can fix them

[image]

What I will do is

```
case when nationality <> 'US' and NATINAL_ID_TYPE = 'VISA' then '99\US only can have [national_id_type]=NID' ELSE NATINAL_ID_TYPE END as NATINAL_ID_TYPE ,
case when nationality <> 'US' and NATINAL_ID_TYPE <> 'NA' AND own_house='YES' then '99\US only with NA can own house' ELSE own_house END as own_house
```

Is this way efficient to detect errors in 40 million Record X 70 Columns

I think this will be very slow...

Can you help me with some tips I can use to provide the errors for dashboarding and cleansing that can be used for performance

Comment: I used pt-archiver for MySQL in past